# 'Block' text in certain format in EditText

Tags: android

Well I don't know how this should be called. Anyone can suggest me on how to do below?

So when user finish to write text in a certain format, the text is 'blocked' and later user can delete whole 'blocked' text instead of each character one by one when they want to.

[image]

Comment: this is probably not an edit text. What I would do would be using a linearlayout, horizontal, with a probably autocomplete edittext, which, upon completion, would add a textview in the layout. The backspace key in the edittext would be handled to delete the previous textview if the edittext were empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "Chips". At least according to Roman Nurik in [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ).

> A growing trend across social and communication-related apps is to
>   afford recipient selection using tokenized auto-completing text fields.
>   This kind of UI is more concise than list-based interfaces, and
>   more visually rich, intuitive (exposes a better mental model), and
>   directly manipulable (manage recipients by touching their token) than
>   comma-separated text fields.

It's basically a heavily customized `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. You can get the implementation for it from the [repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/refs/heads/master/chips). An example is in the AOSP Messaging (i.e. SMS) app, check the [RecipientsEditor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java) class. Seems quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create many items of this type, you should override the EditText type, then include it into your xml.
To identify "user finish to write text in a certain format", add a addTextChangedListener() and when users press "Enter key = finish", you change your edit text layout by wrapping around a shape (define it in drawable/)
Also handle when users press "Delete key", set whole text into empty.